# Possibly wrong string in localization engine

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization

I'm working on the localization of Stack Overflow into Russian. On the Transifex there's a string (actually, three strings for different numbers):

> This changed was reviewed by $numUsers$ and **rejected** $timeAgo$.

I'm not a native speaker but this looks like a grammar mistake. Shouldn't it say "change"? It's most probably used in the Documentation section, but I'm not allowed to beta and can't check by myself.

String numbers are [7515-7517](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/65211466?key=92eb1371593a269451676980f83ab4d4).

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that's a typo. (We should probably also say "$numUsers$ users" instead of just putting a number with no explanation in there. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear: Adam, thank you. I'd like to propose some further improvement, please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: I don’t think the second request is good: The new sentence would be understood such that the change was rejected by all of these _n_ users, acting at the same time. In reality, three users may have said no and one yes, over a period of multiple hours (or days). – This is also why you shouldn’t combine multiple requests in a single question, much less add further requests after the first one has already been voted on etc.

Comment: @chirlu: ok, it sounds reasonable, so I've removed the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the "changed" typo, it is pushed out to transifex already.

Comment: Did you also add the "users" before "$numUsers$", as proposed by Adam Lear?

Comment: Missed that. Will fix.

Comment: I've made a mistake, "users" goes **after** the number, not before.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did :)

Comment: wow, I can see them already.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot our CI build pushes out to transifex immediately, even before we build out.

Comment: Any way ordinary users can see this "transifex" magic at work? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not really. They help with localization work - we import and export strings to their platform, which our community translators get access to.

Comment: Fair enough, just like with moderator tools, that most users can't really see or access,

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: If you are interested in how Transifex works in general, there are many open-source projects there, too, where you can have a look.

Comment: @Oded is the translation project private, or should it be? I was able to download a JSON file from Transifex with all the strings (8436 at the moment) and wonder if it's kind of security breach on their side?

Comment: @ShadowWizard the SO translation projects on Transifex are public